# a given string is valid identifier or keyword in c++

Tags: c++, keyword, identifier, strcmp

This is a code of checking a given string is an `identifier` or a `keyword`. Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>


int main(){

    int i = 0, flag = 0;
    char a[10][10] = {"int", "float", "break", "long", "char", "for", "if", "switch", "else", "while"}, string[10];

    //clrscr();

    printf("Enter a string :");
    gets(string);

    /*----Checking whether the string is in array a[][]----*/

    for(i = 0 ; i < 10; i++){
        if( (strcmp( a[i], string) == 0) )
            flag = 1;
    }

    /*----If it is in the array then it is a keyword----*/

    if( flag == 1)
        printf("\n%s is a keyword ", string);

    /*----Otherwise check whether the string is an identifier----*/
    else{
        flag = 0;
        /*----Checking the 1st character*----*/

        if( (string[0] == '_') || ( isalpha(string[0]) != 0 ) ){
            /*---Checking rest of the characters*---*/
            for(i = 1; string[i] != '\0'; i++)
            if( (isalnum(string[i]) == 0 ) && (string[i]!='_') )
                flag = 1;
        }
        else
            flag = 1;
        if( flag == 0)
            printf("\n%s is an identifier ", string);
        else
            printf("\n%s is neither a keyword nor an identifier ", string);
    }
        getch();
}
```

- I want to do this code more easily. And is it possible to get or identified the 
  all keywords without declaring in the char? And how to do that?

Can S.O provide me that code?

Comment: If your code was more consistently formatted and indented it might be easier to follow the logic.

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you used [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) rather than arrays and character arrays.

Comment: If you have working code to be improved, better ask at [SE Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: how to do that easily by using std::string and std::vector ??
it would be great if you provide me the code @Galik

Comment: @RashedSami This isn't a tutorial writing site. You can google for tutorials or, better still, work from a good book: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: What is this line: `char a[10][10] = {"int", "float", "break", "long", "char", "for", "if", "switch", "else", "while"}, string[10];
`?

Comment: Never use `gets`.

Comment: Your list of keywords is very incomplete (e.g. `class` is missing).

Comment: IMHO, the *easiest* method is to put your keywords (as `std::string`) into a `std::vector<string>`, and use `std::find` to search the vector.  You can use `cin >> ` to input the `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy method:

```
static const std::string keywords[] =
{
  "char", "class", 
  "struct",
  /* ... */
};
static const size_t keyword_quantity =
  sizeof(keywords) / sizeof(keywords[0]);

std::string search_word;
cin >> search_word;

std::string const * const iterator = 
    std::find(&keywords[0], &keywords[keyword_quantity],
              search_word);
if (iterator != &keywords[keyword_quantity])
{
  cout << "Word is a keyword!\n";
}
```

The `std::string` data type makes text or string handling easier.
The `std::find` function is easy so you don't have to write it (and it's already tested).